# Android Download manager doesn't work using TLS1.1 or TLS1.2 on KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-download-manager, tls1.2

I am developing an application that download a big file in Android using Download Manager, the server that I am downloading the file only support TLS1.1 and TLS1.2.

When I run the code on Lollipop API 21 everything works as expected but when I run it on Kitkat API 19 it doesn't work. Changing the server to support TLS1.0 makes it work.

By default Lollipop had enabled TLS1.1 and TLS1.2, however Kitkat doesnt have it enables by default.

There is any way to tell the download manager service to enable TLS1.1 and TLS1.2?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?